# Signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: apt, docker, gnupg

I'm having trouble, while trying to run a docker container with a base ubuntu image.

While attempting to **`RUN apt-get update`**, I'm getting the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
```

But when I try to add the **`key`** like:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C2518248EEA14886
```

I get the following error:

```
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
```

So attempting to install `gnupg` | `gnupg1` | `gnupg2` by **`RUN apt-get install -y gnupg1`** I get the following error.

```
E: Package 'gnupg1' has no installation candidate
```

Here's my Dockerfile for reference just in case:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get install -y gnupg1

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C2518248EEA14886

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gradle \
    oracle-java8-installer \
    oracle-java8-set-default \
    unzip \
    wget \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

---

So if I understand this correctly I need to update `apt-get` to install `gnupg` (or a variation) which I need to update `key chain` but I can't do that unless I update `apt-get`.

So is there a trick/workaround to this cyclic dependency? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'm very new to ubuntu and docker maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep gnupg` to your question.

Comment: `gnupg` and `gnupg2` should be installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 could you help me out a bit, I can't seem to get an output for that command when I added the command in `Dockerfile`. Where am I supposed to add the line?

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried installing all three `gnupg` variations none worked.

Comment: You run this command in a terminal. I have no idea what Dockerfile is.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned I'm attempting to build the image from windows host machine.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`. You removed all lists for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ppa:webupd8team/java` is [discontinued](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). So there is no way to install anything from there.

Remove that PPA from your software sources.

If you don't have any other problems then I see no reason of any other steps.

Comment: Probably out of the scope for this question, I copied the lines from another image (an old one) for dockerfile. However could you tell me if ppa is discontinued how can I install java8 on the docker container? 'Cause I need it.

Comment: You can search how to install Oracle java to Ubuntu. I am unaware of what is docker container.